# Delay/Timer in java

Tags: java

Every method I use so far just freeze's my program for the time but I want the game to continue running, I just want the shield boolean to be true for X time and then return to false after the time has expired, is there any way to do this? Thanks.

```
    c.removeEntity(tempEnt);
c.removeEntity(this);
Game.shield = true;
// Wait x time and then do the line below;
Game.shield = false;
```

Comment: You're going to need to look into threading!

Comment: What SpaceCowboy said. [This documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) is probably a good place to start.

Comment: @TFuto are you sure about that?

Comment: Please tag your framework. Different frameworks have different methods of doing things.

Comment: You'll need multiple threads to do things "at the same time".  You can create/manage your own threads, or look into the Executor interfaces.  Either way, it's complicated if you don't understand the theory behind it.  Another option, and probably your best bet, is to change Game.shield from a boolean to a 'time (or turn) last enabled' -- then you don't have to worry about multithreading, and can just subtract the value of Game.shield from 'now' to see if it should still be on at the time it matters, or when use Game.shield as 'time shield expires'.

Comment: You can try http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

Comment: Try the answer posted below, its working fine.

Answer (score 3):

The people saying you need to look into threading don't quite understand the question, imho.

If you want to give something a timeout in your game, you just have to record the time it started, then check the current time against that start time plus your duration in your game loop. Something like this:

```
long shieldStartTime;
long shieldDuration = 10000; //10 seconds

void startShield(){
   Game.shield = true;
   shieldStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

//advances your game by one frame, whatever your game loop calls
void step(){
   //game loop stuff

   if(Game.shield && System.currentTimeMillis() > shieldStartTime + shieldDuration){
      Game.shield = false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Comment: This will likely stop the entire program unless he is using threading

Comment: Yeah this stopped the whole program :/

Answer (score 0):

Since you failed to mention your framework, I'll suggest this.  If you wrap your game in Swing framework, just use a `javax.swing.Timer`

```
Timer timer = new Timer(delay null);

public Game() {

    timer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Game.stop();
            timer.stop();
        }
    });
}
```

After the delay time is up, the game will stop. You can use `timer.start();` in whatever method you use to start the game.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :-

```
//Your Code here
c.removeEntity(tempEnt);
c.removeEntity(this);
Game.shield = true;
// Wait x time and then do the line below;

int delay = 10000; //delay 10000 milliseconds
try{
    Thread.sleep(delay);
   }catch(InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println("Interrupted ::"+e.getMessage());
   }

Game.shield = false;
//Your code here
```

Its working fine.Hope it will help you.

Comment: I think he's asking how to do it without the program freezing in the process.